# Quotient ring is a domain??

Tags: ring-theory

i wanted to ask this ring theory related question
My question is, is $\frac {\mathbb{C}[X,Y]}{(X^4+X^3Y+Y^4)}$  a domain or not...  i know that for it to be a domain the denominator ideal has to be prime  ideal in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ 
How do i use the fact that the polynomial is homogeneous..
I am a bit new to this topic and would appreciate if somebody would explain this to me.?

Comment: By $C$ do you mean the complex numbers?

Comment: Yes i mean exactly that

Answer (score 3):

By fundamental theorem of algebra $x^4+x^3+1$ can be factorized in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ so similarly $x^4+x^3y+y^4$ can be factorized in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ so the given ring is not an integral domain.

Comment: Frank we use the homogenity in dividing the polynomial by $y^4$ or $x^4$??

Comment: Divide(factor out?) $y^4$

Comment: And the factors that come are non units...

Comment: Not sure what you mean? suppose $x^4+x^3+1=(x-c_1)(x-c_2)(x-c_3)(x-c_4)$ then $x^4+x^3y+y^4=(x-c_1y)(x-c_2y)(x-c_3y)(x-c_4y)$ right?

Comment: Yes and that would contradict the property of a prime ideal??

Comment: Yes because each factor is not in the ideal but product of them is in the ideal. That contradict the definition of prime ideal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37269/discussion-between-frank000-and-upstart).